# How to get time from JDateChooser?

Tags: java, jdatechooser

I'm trying to get the date and time from a `JDateChooser`and put it on a `JTextField`. The date works, but the time doesn't. It shows 00:00:00.

That's my code, what am I missing?

```
jDateChooser1.setDate(java.sql.Date.valueOf(java.time.LocalDate.now())); //Set a standard date to the JDateChooser

 //This part is on a jButton 
    java.util.Date date;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    date = jDateChooser1.getDate();
    String dateTime = (String) sdf.format(jDateChooser1.getDate());

    jTextField1.setText(dateTime);
```

Comment: You have to either use JSpinner or you can use [LGoodDatePicker](https://github.com/LGoodDatePicker/LGoodDatePicker) with is a good alternative to JDateChooser

Comment: So just to make sure I understood... Is not possible to get the time from a JDateChooser or is possible but those are just better options? Thank's anyway, I'll take a look at JSPinner and LGoodDatePicker.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Obtaining date from JDateChooser and displaying it in JTextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377318/obtaining-date-from-jdatechooser-and-displaying-it-in-jtextfield)

Comment: Yes. You are correct besides `LGoodDatePicker` is overall better than `JDateChooser`. Check this out [LGoodDatePicker Demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXgWE.png)

Comment: @alexamdrum He was asking about picking time using `JDateChooser` not the date so I don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: You set java.sql.Date but get java.util.Date. These 2 classes are not the same.

Comment: Curious, what version of JDateChooser are you using?

Comment: @nickolay.laptev Yeah, I didn't see that. I'll check it.

Comment: @DevilsHnd I'm sorry, where can I see that? Is the jCalendar 1.4, if it helps.

Comment: I don't think **JDateChooser** or **JCalendar** provides Time. If you want to add time then append it to a returned **date string** from the chooser before applying it to your JTextField. [This might be worth looking at as well](http://tododifferent.blogspot.com/2013/08/how-to-use-jcalendar-date-picker-in_3497.html). I dunno...I'm old...I like JDatePicker.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `java.sql.Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate`, `ZonedDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, all from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). I know that `JDateChooser` needs a `java.util.Date` and gives you one back. Convert like `jDateChooser1.getDate().toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())` and format the resulting `ZonedDateTime`.